# Commas out of place and weird editing

Tags: resume

I'm a relatively new LaTeX user, and although I have been reading tutorials, I'm in a bit of a hurry to write a CV, so I'm using a template I found on the web. However, now that I'm trying to edit it, it's proven to be a bit challenging and I'm kinda stuck.

```
\cventry{2009- 2012}{}{Bla bla school}{City}{{}}{}  % Arguments not required can be left empty%
%\cventry{2009--2012}{Bachelor of Business Studies}{The University of California}{Berkeley}{Specialized in Commerce}
```

since the rest of the `{}` had to be completed by stuff like GPA or "First Class sth" and were in my case NA, I just deleted the content inside the brackets.

However, the problem was that what resulted was a lot of commas in the wrong places and I can't seem to find how to get rid of them... :(

Comment: Maybe use `\cvline` instead if you don't have too many details?

Comment: Please tell us which template you're using.

Comment: https://www.writelatex.com/298977sytrgx

Comment: I suspect the `{{}}` doesn't count as empty. Maybe try `\cventry{2009- 2012}{}{Bla bla school}{City}{}{}`

Comment: Solved, simple problem with syntax. Thank you all.